# How to find out firmware

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, device-firmware, sony-xperia-z2

How does one determine what firmware they are using? I've looked in settings -> about phone and can't find it. I know I'm using Android 5.1.1 and have CM.

Comment: Could you add more information about "find out firmware"

Comment: @SuperThomasLab for example when they say this is for ".167 firmware", how do I know if I have it? http://techbeasts.com/2015/02/09/boost-sound-xperia-z2-z1-sound-mod/

Comment: or here they talk about firmware 23.1.A.1.28, 23.0.1.A.0.167  and 23.0.1.A.0.167  http://xperiafirmware.com/8-firmware/51-sony-xperia-z2-d6503

Answer (score 3):

It depends and differs by the mobile manufactures.

For Sony, Samsung and Motorola devices you can find in `Settings > About phone > Build Number`.

If you have a Samsung device you can also check the version of firmware you currently have by dialing `*#1234#`.

In HTC devices it will be under `Settings > About Device > Software Information > Software Version`. (eg. 3.16.401.9)

The firmware number consists of several elements, all of which are essential for the functioning of the phone:

```
- PDA: Android operating system and your customizations.
- Phone: the actual identifier of your device.
- CSC (Country Exit Code): the languages and country-specific parameters.
- Bootloader: the boot loader program that runs at startup to all unit processes.
```

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot_1]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge image(Source - [Ref](https://www.androidpit.com/what-is-my-firmware-number))</sub>

Comment: Which part of the build number is the firmware version?

Comment: The settings menu shows the firmware version as the build number in samsung and Software number in htc device.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old thread, others may find it by a search as I just did. On my Chinese tablet I have not found a way to relate the displayed build number of the firmware (V1.0.0_V7 - but V7 is the hardware version) with a downloadable version. However, Aida64 tells me that there is a file */system/build.prop* described as Build Properties; examining that file, which is text, I find a great mass of information, thought not a build number as such. In my case I have a build *date*, which solves my problem: it is earlier than the date of the firmware I can download. I suppose the details are likely to vary from one device to another, but the general approach may be the best if there is no clear information. Some of the information displayed by "About" is not that useful; apparently my serial number is 0123456789ABCDEF